# VS Code: Single keybinding to Spit/Merge Editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to detect the split/single states of the editor so I can use a single keybinding to split and merge an editor?

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+\\",
  "command": "workbench.action.splitEditorDown"
  "when": "EDITOR IS IN SINGLE STATE"
},
{
  "key": "ctrl+\\",
  "command": "workbench.action.editorLayoutSingle",
  "when": "EDITOR IS IN SPLIT STATE"
}
```

Or perhaps there is a different way to set this up?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this what you are looking for:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+\\",
  "command": "workbench.action.splitEditorDown",
  "when": "!multipleEditorGroups"
},
{
  "key": "ctrl+\\",
  "command": "workbench.action.editorLayoutSingle",
  "when": "multipleEditorGroups"
}
```

I found that `when` clause by using the `Developer: Inspect Context Keys` command.

(1) open the Developer Tools Console: `Help/Toggle Developer Tools`
(2) run the above command from the Command Palette and click anywhere in an editor
(3) that will create a large object in the Developer Tools Console that has a lot of `when` context clauses with their current values
(4) do a find in the Console for `groups` and look for a promising `when` clause (I first searched with the term `split` but nothing was helpful).

There is nothing to tell you if a specific file is split into two (or more) groups though - only that there are 1 or more groups of editors.